# Can't remove the space under my nav bar

Tags: html, css

There is a little space between me nav bar and main div which I want to remove. Same is the case with footer (main div contains all the content except footer and nav). I've tried 
margin : 0
margin-bottom : 0 
padding : 0
etc nd stuff but its not working.

I've checked the code several times but can't find the problem. I've also searched on google but its only confusing me.

I'm new to coding so there's quite a possibility for dumb mistakes :) .

```
<! DOCTYPE html>

<html lang = "en" >

<head>

    <base href = "D:\workstation\my webpages\3rd day\" />
    <title>
    Home
    </title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href= "style.css" />
</head>

<body >

<nav id = "top-menu" >
    <ul>
        <li><a href = "home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href = "rock.html">Rock</a></li>
        <li><a href = "paper.html">Paper</a></li>
        <li><a href = "sci.html">Scissor</a></li>
        <li><a href = "contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href = "buy.html">Buy</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div id = "maindiv" >

<header>
    <hgroup>
    <h1> Rock Paper Scissors Corporation </h1>
    <h2>Who Will Win!?</h2>
    </hgroup>
    <p>Oh, the suspense!</p>
</header>

<p class = "message" > Game status: Using HTML5 Drag and Drop</p>
<!--
<section id = "rpsgame">

<div id = "dnd" >
    <div >      
        <img src = "D:\workstation\Ex_Files_HTML_EssT_2012\Free Exercise Files\Chap17\images\rock.png" height = 240px width = 240px /><footer>Rock</footer>
    </div>

    <div>   
        <img src = "D:\workstation\Ex_Files_HTML_EssT_2012\Free Exercise Files\Chap17\images\paper.png" height = 240px width = 240px /><footer>paper</footer>
    </div>

    <div>
        <img src = "D:\workstation\Ex_Files_HTML_EssT_2012\Free Exercise Files\Chap17\images\scissors.png" height = 240px width = 240px /><footer>scissors</footer>
    </div>

    </div>

</section>
 --> 

<div class = "clear" ></div>
</div> <!-- main div ends here --> 


<footer class = "foot">
    <p>Copyright © 2017 Hamza waqar practice document</p>
</footer>

</body>

</html>






/*css starts from here*/

/*menu formating starts */

    body { 
        width : 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color : #a60;
    }
    nav#top-menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #531;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

    #top-menu ul {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
    #top-menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    max-height: 35px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0;
    font-family: tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #531;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #da1;

}
    #top-menu ul li a:hover { border-bottom: 2px solid brown;}
/*menu ends*/

body, p {
    line-height: 1;
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    font-size: 16pt;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: tahoma, sans-serif;
    color: #531;
    margin: .25ex 12pt;
}

h1 { font-size : 200% }
h2 {
    font-size: 130%;
    color: #840; }

    header p {
    font-family: tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 85%;
    margin: .25ex 12pt;
    color: #531;
        }

#maindiv {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto ;
    padding : 0;
    background-color: #eec;
}

p.message {
    width: 766px;
    margin: .5ex 0;
    font: normal 1em Tahoma, sans-serif;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: #da1;
    color: black;
    margin-left : 20px;
    margin-top :20px;
}

section#rpsGame {
    margin: 1em;
}

#dnd div {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #da1;
}

#dnd footer {
    background-color: #da1;
    font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px 0;
}

.clear {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    clear: both;
}

footer.foot {
            width : 100%;
            margin : 0;
            padding :0;
            background-color : grey;
            height : 40px;
            width : 100%;

           }

footer.foot p {  color: #ccc;
    font-size: 70%;
    font-family: tahoma, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you use 'inspect element' in your browser?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @Hamza Waqar  Perhaps adding an marked-up screen shot will make your image problem more clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your margin of h1 element to 0 (it causes this issue)

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: tahoma, sans-serif;
    color: #531;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Elements such as `<ul>` and `<p>` will receive margins from the browser unless you specify otherwise. I would bet that the space you are seeing is a result of a margin being applied to the unordered list in your `<nav>`.

There are a couple of approaches you can take to resolve this issue.

In your stylesheet you could add the following:

```
#top-menu ul {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Alternatively you could add a generic class that removes padding. Here is an example.

```
<nav id="top-menu">
    <ul class="no-padding">
        <li><a href = "home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href = "rock.html">Rock</a></li>
        <li><a href = "paper.html">Paper</a></li>
        <li><a href = "sci.html">Scissor</a></li>
        <li><a href = "contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href = "buy.html">Buy</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And in your stylesheet you could add the following:

```
.no-padding {
    padding: 0;
}
```